# Configuring RabbitMQ with Magento 2: Bulk Queue Pending

Tags: magento2, api, rabbit-mq

I am trying to integrate RabbitMQ with Magento 2 to access bulk endpoints

**Bitnami Magento ver. 2.4.6-p2**

I have successfully set up RabbitMQ with my Magento 2 instance, and now bulk requests are being sent to the queue. However, I'm facing challenges with requests processing - either the requests aren't processed as expected, or there's an error that I'm not able to pinpoint.

**My magento-values.yaml file:**

```
magentoUsername: user
magentoPassword: p@ssword123
magentoHost: magento.company.com
mariadb:
  auth:
    rootPassword: p@ssword123
    password: p@ssword123
ingress:
  enabled: true
  pathType: Prefix
  hostname: magento.company.com
  path: /
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/appgw-ssl-certificate: dev-certs-com
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-private-ip: "true"
  tls: true

extraVolumes:
  - name: cron-file
    configMap:
      name: magento-cron

extraVolumeMounts:
  - name: cron-file
    mountPath: /etc/cron.d
    readOnly: true
```

**My rabbitmq-deployment.yaml file:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: dev-magento-ns
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq
        image: rabbitmq:3-management
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5672
        - containerPort: 15672

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: dev-magento-ns
spec:
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  ports:
    - name: amqp
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5672
      targetPort: 5672
    - name: management
      protocol: TCP
      port: 15672
      targetPort: 15672
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**After this I ran this:**
`php bin/magento setup:config:set --amqp-host="52.234.243.215" --amqp-port="5672" --amqp-user="guest" --amqp-password="guest" --amqp-virtualhost="/"`

**Then I ran this:** `php bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all`

**And when I check it in magento2 pod, I get:**

```
I have no name!@my-magento-59f6bdcbd5-pp8vp:/bitnami/magento$ ps aux | grep 'queue:consumers:start'
1001         589  0.0  0.9 689768 162860 pts/0   S    Dec11   0:02 php bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all
1001      288196  0.0  0.0   3240  1664 pts/16   S+   10:52   0:00 grep queue:consumers:start
I have no name!@my-magento-59f6bdcbd5-pp8vp:/bitnami/magento$
```

**My env.php:**

```
.
.
.
    'queue' => [
        'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 1,
        'amqp' => [
            'host' => '53.243.234.211',
            'port' => '5672',
            'user' => 'guest',
            'password' => 'guest',
            'virtualhost' => '/'
        ]
    ],
.
.
.
    'cron_consumers_runner' => [
        'cron_run' => true,
        'max_messages' => 10000,
        'consumers' => [
            'product_action_attribute.update',
            'product_action_attribute.website.update',
            'exportProcessor',
            'media.storage.catalog.image.resize',
            'matchCustomerSegmentProcessor',
            'codegeneratorProcessor',
            'sales.rule.update.coupon.usage',
            'sales.rule.quote.trigger.recollect',
            'product_alert',
            'staging.synchronize_entity_period',
            'negotiableQuotePriceUpdate',
            'sharedCatalogUpdatePrice',
            'sharedCatalogUpdateCategoryPermissions',
            'inventory.source.items.cleanup',
            'inventory.mass.update',
            'inventory.reservations.cleanup',
            'inventory.reservations.update',
            'inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus',
            'inventory.indexer.sourceItem',
            'inventory.indexer.stock',
            'media.content.synchronization',
            'media.gallery.renditions.update',
            'media.gallery.synchronization',
            'placeOrderProcessor',
            'purchaseorder.toorder',
            'purchaseorder.transactional.email',
            'purchaseorder.validation',
            'quoteItemCleaner',
            'inventoryQtyCounter',
            'async.operations.all'
        ]
    ]    
];
```

**Then I performed a bulk operation using curl:**

```
# Get bearer token
C:\Users\ikrkhan\schemamagento>curl -X POST "https://magento.company.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"username\":\"user\", \"password\":\"p@ssword123\"}"
"adsadsdadadadadsadsadLCJleHAiOjE3MDI1NjAzNjV9.5D3zk5fyTUHrknTLcPEVlYlgl7fNPSbwWk7H-nqvbZ4"
```

```
# POST products in bulk
C:\Users\ikrkhan\schemamagento>curl -X POST "https://magento.company.com/rest/all/async/bulk/V1/products" -H "Authorization: Bearer adsadsdadadadadsadsadLCJleHAiOjE3MDI1NjAzNjV9.5D3zk5fyTUHrknTLcPEVlYlgl7fNPSbwWk7H-nqvbZ4" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @bulk_add_test.json
{"bulk_uuid":"13f2a323-cfbe-47c5-a54d-be6d8dc141bb","request_items":[{"id":0,"data_hash":"684841f654k2jbk2j4bjk2b42k42jb8e9f75684d3","status":"accepted"},{"id":1,"data_hash":"b823a2adsa4342kj24kjn422kj42n2kj32370019c4c85e9","status":"accepted"},{"id":2,"data_hash":"619bcd1536e501b4590877a0909750bcfecd2912882ae2e92a38392b25ea6bc8","status":"accepted"},{"id":3,"data_hash":"5dadawad016106bc9c59d1b566f16awdadadawdadaw34a4","status":"accepted"},{"id":4,"data_hash":"eb7bbc8b26542bkj2b4kj2b4k24bkj2b42k4j42jndee4c4af2e6","status":"accepted"},{"id":5,"data_hash":"bc3742050682f6464d3be2cad56b277996f9b057e1ea0ddd4ef01f70686fb3ad","status":"accepted"},{"id":6,"data_hash":"bd480a8a517ac76j2kbk42bkj4b2kjbkj2442j5d732adc","status":"accepted"},{"id":7,"data_hash":"ff54d258a701904b2kjjk24b2kj4bj2b4jk244d337cd722f","status":"accepted"},{"id":8,"data_hash":"e0a65a6764aa53a6b5kj2b4kj2bkj42bjk4b2521c126832371006","status":"accepted"}],"errors":false}
C:\Users\ikrkhan\schemamagento>curl -X GET "https://magento.company.com/rest/V1/bulk/13f2a323-cfbe-47c5-a54d-be6d8dc141bb/status" -H "Authorization: Bearer adsadsdadadadadsadsadLCJleHAiOjE3MDI1NjAzNjV9.5D3zk5fyTUHrknTLcPEVlYlgl7fNPSbwWk7H-nqvbZ4"
{"operations_list":[{"id":0,"status":4,"result_message":null,"error_code":null},{"id":1,"status":4,"result_message":null,"error_code":null},{"id":2,"status":4,"result_message":null,"error_code":null},{"id":3,"status":4,"result_message":null,"error_code":null},{"id":4,"status":4,"result_message":null,"error_code":null},{"id":5,"status":4,"result_message":null,"error_code":null},{"id":6,"status":4,"result_message":null,"error_code":null},{"id":7,"status":4,"result_message":null,"error_code":null},{"id":8,"status":4,"result_message":null,"error_code":null}],"user_type":2,"bulk_id":"13f2a323-cfbe-47c5-a54d-be6d8dc141bb","description":"Topic async.magento.catalog.api.productrepositoryinterface.save.post","start_time":"2023-12-14 12:33:15","user_id":1,"operation_count":9}
```

**But now it is stuck in pending status:**

[image]

[image]

What steps can I take to diagnose and resolve this issue?
Any pointers are welcomed. Thanks!